# What is 'pgfcore.sty file not found' error? How to fix it?

Tags: beamer, packages, installing

I am an amateur user, just using latex for the past one week. When I ran a sample presentation (from the book "Practical Latex" by George Gratzer), I get this error message that a particular file called `pgfcore.sty` is missing.
I have installed the `beamer` package from the MiKTeX console.

Should I find the missing file and manually install it? If yes, how to do that?
I'm stuck at this point and I will be very grateful if you could help me with this?
I am using MiKTeX version 2.9 with Windows10 OS.

[image: This is the error message I get while typesetting]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: Above the error you can see a message that the pgf package couldn't be installed. Go to the miktex console and try to install it there: select pgf in the package tab.

Answer (score 1):

While using LaTeX various packages are used.

In case the package is not available then it is downloaded from the net on the fly and installed.

`pgfcore.sty` is one such package.

You need to install the package. The easiest way to do that is from the Start Menu->All Programs->MikTEX 2.9->Maintenance (Admin)->Package Manager (Admin) and search for the package you need.

You can also open the Settings (Admin) shortcut from that same folder, and choose "Ask me every time" to the option "Install packages automatically". Then, when you compile the document, MikTEX should ask you if you want to install missing packages.

Note: You cannot answer "Yes" to that option because MikTEX won't have admin priviliges when it tries to install the new package, and it won't work.